# How to connect to node.js Websocket server with vb.net client

Tags: node.js, vb.net, websocket

I am coding a small Websocket server with node.js.
I need to connect to this server with the vb.net client.
I think I use the ClientWebSocket class but I can not find any examples to start.
Would anyone have an example or link to help me find the first leads for coding this vb.net client?
Thank you